# Dynamic execution of gitlab-ci jobs

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a job called 'job1' which checks something. Depending on this result 'job2' or 'job3' should be executed. I tried it with the build.env artifact. But the environment variable `EXIT_CODE` is only available in the script section and not in the `rules` or `only` job annotations. Then I tried it with global variables (`variables: EXIT_CODE: "0"`) and trying to set them in the script section of 'job1'. But this doesn't work as well. How I'am supposed to execute job 2/3 depending on some results of job1

```
stages:
  - check
  - merge

variables:
  EXIT_CODE: "0"

job1:
  stage: check
  image: ubuntu:20.10
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - set +e
    - git merge --ff-only github/master
    - EXIT_CODE=4
    - EXIT_CODE="4"
      # - echo "EXIT_CODE=$?" >> build.env
      # - cat build.env
      #artifacts:
      #  reports:
      #    dotenv: build.env

job2:
  stage: merge
  dependencies:
    - job1
  rules:
    - if: '$EXIT_CODE == "0"'
  script:
    - echo "WILL FAIL $EXIT_CODE"
      #  only:
      #    variables:
      #      - $EXIT_CODE == "128"

job3:
  stage: merge
  dependencies:
    - job1
  script:
    - echo "WILL success"
  only:
    variables:
      - $EXIT_CODE == "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put in your `job2` definition:

```
job2:
  stage: merge
  when: on_success
```

then it should only be executed when job1 succeeds, i.e, when its exit code is "0".

Comment: Ok thanks thats fine for 2 following jobs. But If i have job2, job3 and job4. Execute job2 when exit code of job1 is 0. Execute job3 when exit code of job1 is 1 and execute job4 when exit code of job1 ist 128

Comment: @SamuelTJackson: I guess you should be able to achieve case 1 and 2 with a mix of on_success (all jobs from prior stages succeed) and on_failure (at least one job from prior stages fails) and always. *But* I don't think you can easily have more than two possible states for a job because there are issues requesting that (see for instance https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/273157 requesting more than one failure state). Otherwise you can also pass files/data from one job to another with artifacts and `dependencies` and try to manage this manually..